# What's the use for a HAVING clause when we already have the WHERE clause?

Tags: sqlite

Beginner in SQLite here.

I was learning about the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses in SQLite. I get what the GROUP BY clause is used for. And I get that the HAVING clause is applied to the group returned by the GROUP BY clause. But is it really necessary to use it when we have the WHERE clause?

For example:
I have a table called sales containing the following:

```
id          item_name   price       month
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Bike        500.0       October
2           Hammer      25.0        October
3           Rope        50.0        November
4           Screw       10.0        November
```

This query:

```
SELECT month,count(*) FROM sales WHERE price > 35 GROUP BY month;
```

and this one:

```
SELECT month,count(*) FROM sales WHERE price > 35 GROUP BY month HAVING (price > 35);
```

return the same results. I'm wondering if I'm not using the HAVING clause for the exact purpose that it was designed for. Because I ran another set of queries:

```
SELECT month,count(*) FROM sales GROUP BY month HAVING (price > 35);
SELECT month,count(*) FROM sales WHERE price > 35 GROUP BY month HAVING (price > 35);
```

and they both return different answers.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice the difference if you'll add one more function, `sum(price)`:

```sql
select
  month
, count(*)
, sum(price)
from sales

where price > 35

group by month
;
```

this filters data first (with `where` clause), and then groups it. Since it groups after filtering, `count(*)` gives 1.

Where as

```
select
  month
, count(*)
, sum(price)
from sales

group by month
having price > 35
;
```

runs on unfiltered data (no `where` clause), but `sum`s only items which `having price > 35`. Since it runs on unfiltered data, `count(*)` gives 2.

Comment: I checked the answer out and read through a few blogs and got it. Thanks for the help.